# pd.read_csv : can't separate items with commas between quotes

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file I'm trying to read with pd.read_csv.

Some lines are just fine but other lines are grouped in the first column & the rest are filled with nan values. The problem is with those lines that have commas in the title column & are therefore grouped between quotes, like this:

```
Apples,Oranges,5,"These are apples, red, and oranges, orange",2;
```

If you open the same file with the text editor, it looks like this:

```
"Apples,Oranges,5,""These are apples, red, and oranges, orange"",2";
```

I tried a lot of different things (such as delimiter=',', quotechar='"') but nothing seems to work.

[image: Here's a screenshot]

Any advice?

Comment: Can you share the code used and a minimal reproducible example ?

Comment: @abokey I tried just pd.read_csv(file) & pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

Comment: What exactly is the delimiter there? Is it supposed to be the coma? If so, your data structure makes no sense since strings are very suscetible to have comas as separator would indicate that you use a different delimiter such as |. When saving you csv

Comment: @BrunoEgan, I can't reproduce the issue. Can you show with a screenshot the output you're getting ? Also, what version of pandas are you using ? `print(pd.__version__)`

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1 I agree but unfortunately I have no control over the format of these files as they're being provided by a third party

Comment: @abokey I've just attached a screenshot. Pandas version is 1.3.4. Thanks for your interest!

Comment: @BrunoEgan, I still can't reproduce the issue since I don't have an example of your text/csv file. Can you try  `pd.read_csv(file, doublequote=False)` ?

Comment: That line you showed us is encoded to very specifically say it has only one column filled. No options to any CSV reader will ignore that. You will need to pre-process the file to remove the outer quotes before reading the line. Whatever process created the file "thought" it was only one column and decided it had to quote the line to protect the double quotes it contained.

Comment: You could write a preprocessor that detects lines enclosed entirely in double quotes, and remove the outer double quotes and replace the double-double quotes by just one double quotes.

Comment: A possibly simpler solution: for each record you read, if there is only one column, put its contents back into a StringIO buffer and reopen it as if it was another csv containing just one line. That will be much more reliable, giving proper CSV parsing twice for those individual lines, which appears to be what you need here.

Comment: Translating that idea into pandas terminology, look for rows with one non-NaN value in the first column and all NaN's in the rest of the row, and reparse that value into the full row. I just tried to give you some code to do this, but I'm not familiar enough with Pandas to figure it out quickly, so you'll have to do that part of the work yourself, or maybe someone else here will.

Comment: @BrunoEgan Was either answer below helpful to you?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try using something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd


def fix_row(row: pd.Series, column_name: str) -> pd.Series:
    """Split a row into multiple rows if `column_name` is a comma separated string.

    Parameters
    ----------
    row : pd.Series
        The row to split.
    column_name : str
        The name of the column to split.

    Returns
    -------
    pd.Series
        The original row, or row created from splitting `column_name`.
    """
    value = row[column_name]
    formated_value = str(value).split(',')
    if len(formated_value) > 1:
        return pd.Series(dict(zip(row.keys(), formated_value)))
    return row


# == Example ==================================================

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": ["1234,2022-02-02,10", "1234", "EBX10", "EBX20,2022-02-02,10"],
        "col2": [None, "2022-02-02", "2022-03-02", None],
        "col3": [None, 10, 50, None],
    }
)
# Dataframe `df` looks like this:
#
#                   col1        col2  col3
# 0   1234,2022-02-02,10        None   NaN   <-- Column with formating problem
# 1                 1234  2022-02-02  10.0
# 2                EBX10  2022-03-02  50.0
# 3  EBX20,2022-02-02,10        None   NaN   <-- Column with formating problem

# Call `fix_row` function using apply, and specify the name of the column
# to maybe split into multiple columns.
new_df = df.apply(fix_row, column_name='col1', axis=1)

# Dataframe `new_df` looks like this:
#
#     col1        col2  col3
# 0   1234  2022-02-02    10
# 1   1234  2022-02-02  10.0
# 2  EBX10  2022-03-02  50.0
# 3  EBX20  2022-02-02    10
```

### Notes on `fix_row` function

The `fix_row` function works based on a couple of assumptions that need to be true, in order for it to work:

1. The function assumes that values from `column_name` parameter (in the example above, `'col1'`), will only contain multiple commas, when there's a formatting problem.
2. When there's a row to fix, the function assumes that all the row values need to be replaced with the values from the `column_name` you specify, and they are in the correct order.

### Input and Output from the Example

**Input Pandas DataFrame `df`:**

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234,2022-02-02,10 |  | nan |
| 1234 | 2022-02-02 | 10 |
| EBX10 | 2022-03-02 | 50 |
| EBX20,2022-02-02,10 |  | nan |

**Output from `df.apply(fix_row, column_name='col1', axis=1)`:**

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2022-02-02 | 10 |
| 1234 | 2022-02-02 | 10 |
| EBX10 | 2022-03-02 | 50 |
| EBX20 | 2022-02-02 | 10 |

### Variations to `fix_row` you might consider trying

Instead of checking the length of the `formated_value`, you might swap the `if` condition statement, checking whether the other values from the row are empty or not. You could do that using something like this:

```py
def fix_row(row: pd.Series, column_name: str) -> pd.Series:
    value = row[column_name]
    formated_value = str(value).split(',')
    if row[[col for col in row.keys() if col != column_name]].isna().all():
        return pd.Series(dict(zip(row.keys(), formated_value)))
    return row
```

Comment: I like this answer - upvoted it - but does it handle those inner doubled double quotes correctly, and the presence of commas within those doubled double quotes?

Comment: @joanis It handled correctly on the examples I've used to test the solution, but you never know. The only way to be certain is by testing on the intended data.

Comment: I guess I'd test on the two lines OP provided, at least. I am not sure if `"Apples,Oranges,5,""These are apples, red, and oranges, orange"",2";` would be handled correctly, so that's specifically what I would test on. I believe that should yield a single field with the value `These are apples, red, and oranges, orange` not split on its commas, and with the double quotes removed, although I have to concede the screen capture does not show such an example.

Comment: I think the equivalent with the way you are initializing the data would be `... "col1": ['"apples,oranges",2022-02-02,10', ...` and `new_df[0][0]` should contain `apples,oranges`.

Comment: @joanis wouldn't it end up being similar to the example I used? In the example, some of the values for "col1" contain all the values in the actual row should have. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, I just tested your code with my suggested data change, and I end up with `new_df[0][0]` having `"apples` and `new_df[1][0]` having `oranges"`, which is not correct. `2022-02-02` ends up in row0 col3 instead of row0 col2, as a consequence, and the `10` in the row just disappears.

Answer (score 1):

While doing my jogging, your question was bugging me, because of that `;` you showed at the end of both your good and your bad lines. Lines in a CSV file don't usually end in a semi colon!

My theory is that your file was created by a process that wrote a semi-colon-separated-value file containing in column 0 the contents of each comma-separated-value line. That process had to escape double quotes it saw in the standard way, which is why it put double quotes around the field and replaced each double quote within the field with a doubled double quote.

If that theory is correct, what you can do is read the file twice, once as a semi-colon-separated-value file, and then the contents of column 0 as a CSV file.

Here's code that does exactly that:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import io

buffer = io.StringIO()
with open("file.mixed-sv", newline="") as mixed_sv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(mixed_sv_file, delimiter=";")
    for row in reader:
        print(row[0], file=buffer)

buffer.seek(0)
df = pd.read_csv(buffer)
print("df:\n", df)
```

Given this input file, which I'm calling `file.mixed-sv` to highlight it's not pure CSV:

```
Fruit1,Fruit2,N,Notes,M;
Apples,Oranges,5,"These are apples, red, and oranges, orange",2;
"Apples,Oranges,5,""These are apples, red, and oranges, orange"",2";
```

my script outputs:

```
df:
    Fruit1   Fruit2  N                                       Notes  M
0  Apples  Oranges  5  These are apples, red, and oranges, orange   2
1  Apples  Oranges  5  These are apples, red, and oranges, orange   2
```

Notes:

- I'm using the `csv` module rather than Pandas for the initial filter, a) because I understand it better, but b) because at this stage of processing, you really don't need the power of Pandas, you just need to parse the file and extract the first field.
- If your file is big, this is going to take a lot of memory because I end up with 2 copies of it in memory at the same time. If you need something more memory efficient, replace my StringIO buffer by an actual temporary file on disk.
- EDIT: my original version had three copies in memory, but I just realized I could use `buffer.seek(0)` to bring it back to the beginning instead of creating a new one from its contents.